# Two dimensional array of pointers to structure (dynamic)

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, malloc, structure

so i'm working on a piece of code that should use a table of pointers to structures; here you have that structure type

```
 #define liczbafunkcji 5
 #define wielkosclasu 0
 typedef struct drzewo typ;
 struct drzewo {

    typ *right;
    typ *left;
    typ *up;
    char znak;
    unsigned int instrukcje;
    unsigned int opcje;
    float value;
  };
 typ * t[wielkosclasu][rozmiar];
```

and here you have an assigning function

```
void przydziel(void)
{
int i,g;

for(i=0;i<wielkosclasu;i++)
{
    for(g=0;g<rozmiar;i++)
    {
            t[i][g]=(typ*)malloc(sizeof(typ));
    }
}
}
```

So when i'm doing something like that
      (*t[numerdrzewa][0]).up=NULL;
it goes with " SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault." (checked with gdb) in that line, and i'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Just so you know, `t[numerdrzewa][0]->up` works the same way as you've got there and requires no additional brackets. As a more general case, `(*ptr).something` is equivalent to `ptr->something`.

Comment: Something like `typ * t[0][rozmiar];` should never compile, C dosn't allow arrays to be empty. So you are not showing us what really is going on.

Answer (score 1):

`wielkosclasu` is `0`, so the array is empty and `t[numerdrzewa][0]` would always be outside the array. Also, your function does nothing.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure you're right. But, that function should assign memory to array randomly, so it wouldnt store whole blocks of structures in one place in memory. That was what it should do.